# Trying to get Websockify/noVNC to work through a reverse proxy

Tags: apache, google-chrome, firefox, websocket, vnc

I'm trying to figure out how to get noVNC to work through a reverse proxy, and while it works if I connect directly to it, it doesn't seem to work if I try to reverse proxy.

namely:

I run it as `./utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5901`

if I connect to it as `https://<machine>:6080/vnc.html?host=<machine>&port=6080`

it works fine and I can connect to the vnc session

However, I want to be able to connect to it via a reverse proxy over port 443.

In Apache 2.4.10 (-8 in Debian Jessie), I've configured my proxy line to be

```
ProxyPass /home http://127.0.0.1:6080/
ProxyPassReverse /home http://127.0.0.1:6080/
ProxyPass /websockify wss://127.0.0.1:6080/websockify retry=3
ProxyPassReverse /websockify wss://127.0.0.1:6080/websockify retry=3
```

and I connect to it as `https://<machine>/vnc.html?host=<machine>&port=6080`

This still works, as while the fetch of the html/javascript is going through the reverse proxy, I'm still telling the websocket connection to go over 6080 and it works.

However, when I change it to `https://<machine>/vnc.html?host=<machine>&port=443`

I get the html/javascript just fine, but when it goes to make the connection, in firefox (and chrome and IE, but this error is from firefox in specific) I quickly get

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://<machine>/websockify.
```

and in noVNC I see the error message

```
127.0.0.1: ignoring socket not ready
```

Comment: A large part of this motivation is to enable me to keep an ssh port forwading session alive on the "jump host" and have noVNC only listen on localhost so I can password protect access to it.  Further benefit would be enabling it to work even in restricted environments when I can only access it over 443.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, if one wants to proxy websockets through an https proxy, one should make the proxy part normal websockets (ws://) not secure web sockets (wss://) which makes sense as the https proxy would have handled the ssl portion already and there is nothing to do.

```
ProxyPass /websockify ws://127.0.0.1:6080/websockify retry=3
ProxyPassReverse /websockify ws://127.0.0.1:6080/websockify retry=3
```

make that change and everything works.

Comment: are you certain the websocket stream is encrypted in this setup, and have you a citation or a way I could verify this? I'm considering it for WAN use so everything must be encrypted.

Comment: yes, apache is doing ssl termination.  it wouldn't work otherwise as its making an ssl connection to apache.